# Datepicking Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have implemented a datepick in android studio, but I want to make some changes. I want to make unchoosable the dates before today and all the sundays, and want to make the first choosable date at least 3 days after the current day. For example if today is Friday, I want the first choosable day to be Wednesday (as Sunday is unchoosable). How to implement this?

xml:

```
   <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dpTake"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

java:

```
private DatePicker dpTake;
dpTake=(DatePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dpTake);
    int day=dpTake.getDayOfMonth();
    int month=dpTake.getMonth();
    int year=dpTake.getYear();
        String dateTake = String.valueOf(year)+"-"+String.valueOf(month)+"-"+String.valueOf(day);
        order.setDate_take(dateTake);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datePicker.setMinDate(value);
```

This line will set the minimum date. Now the value would be:

```
long value = ((day + 3) * convert_to_milliseconds) -System.currentTimeMillis();
```

You have converted 3 days from Today into MilliSeconds (however, if you take your input at 7 am in the morning, 3 days will be counted at 7 am in the morning on 3 days later, do some programming if you want to fix at 12 am!).

Cheers!

ReEdit: 
This might work>

```
if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 
                Calendar.SUNDAY) {

        <  ..... Toast or SnackBar etc! ...... >

            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! and how to make Sunday unchoosable? or at least when somebody chooses Sunday, always display a toast or a message to choose another day and return the chosen value to the previous chosen date?

Comment: @AndrewT, does that help?

Comment: anyway I cannot make Sunday unchoosable

Comment: I want to make so that if Sunday is chosen, automatically make Monday the chosen day

Comment: @AndrewT, bad design. but make if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK + 1)

Comment: in this case it works, and the variable holds the correct day value, but the user anyway can see the selected day Sunday

Comment: I want to pass the selected day to monday

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `DatePicker.setMinDate()` method.
For ex.
Create `Calendar` instance:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-3); //-3 means 3 days before.
dpTake.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```